# Error creating a prtools dataset prdataset() with char labels

Tags: matlab, statistics, dataset

I have problems creating my prtools dataset.
the function prdataset returns an error:

```
Error using prdataset (line 266)
Illegal datatype

Error in LoadData (line 35)
prdat=prdataset(data,labels,'featlab',featlab);
```

I detected the error is caused by the ‘labels’ (2nd parameter) which is a char matrix (see image) and should be one of the types accepted by the prdataset function (is either integer or char).

This is my code:

```
% Parameters
Nfeatures=16;
Ninstances=20000;
Ntr_inst=16000;
Ntst_inst=Ninstances-Ntr_inst;

% Load file
fid = fopen('letter-recognition.data');
parsed_file = textscan(fid,'%c%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8%u8','delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
data=cell2mat(parsed_file(2:Nfeatures+1));
labels=parsed_file{1};
featlab=[ ...
    'x-box'; ...    %horizontal position of box (integer)
    'y-box'; ...    %vertical position of box   (integer)
    'width'; ...    %width of box (integer)
    'hight'; ...    %height of box (integer)
    'onpix'; ...    %total # on pixels (integer)
    'x-bar'; ...    %mean x of on pixels in box (integer)
    'y-bar'; ...    %mean y of on pixels in box (integer)
    'x2bar'; ...    %mean x variance (integer)
    'y2bar'; ...    %mean y variance (integer)
    'xybar'; ...    %mean x y correlation (integer)
    'x2ybr'; ...    %mean of x * x * y (integer)
    'xy2br'; ...    %mean of x * y * y (integer)
    'x-ege'; ...    %mean edge count left to right (integer)
    'xegvy'; ...    %correlation of x-ege with y (integer)
    'y-ege'; ...    %mean edge count bottom to top (integer)
    'yegvx'; ...    %correlation of y-ege with x (integer)
];

prdat=prdataset(data,labels,'featlab',featlab);

% Separate train and test
[prtrain, prtest]=gendat(pr_data,Ntr_inst);

% Save dataset
save('letter-recognition-prdataset.mat', 'prtrain', 'prtest');
```

the line causing the error is `prdat=prdataset(data,labels,'featlab',featlab);`

The image shows the type of the labels variable

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out. It wasn't at all about the labels. prdataset expects `double` data. And I had `uint8` due to `%u8` in `textscan`
adding `double(data)` made the trick!